# Minimum across cumulative sums with different starting indices

Tags: r, algorithm, time-series, cumulative-sum

**Question:** Given a vector, I want to know the minimum of a series of cumulative sums, where each cumulative sum is calculated for an increasing starting index of the vector and a fixed ending index (1:5, 2:5, ..., 5:5). Specifically, I am wondering if this can be calculated w/o using a `for()` loop, and if there is potentially a term for this algorithm/ calculation. I am working in R.

**Context:** The vector of interest contains a time series of pressure changes. I want to know of the largest (or smallest) net change in pressure across a range of starting points but with a fixed end point.

**Details + Example:**

```
#Example R code    
diffP <- c(0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0)
minNet1 <- min(cumsum(diffP))
minNet1 #over the whole vector, the "biggest net drop" (largest magnitude with negative sign) is -1.
#However, if I started a cumulative sum in the second half of diffP, I would get a net pressure change of -2.
hold <- list()
nDiff <- length(diffP)
for(j in 1:nDiff){
   hold[[j]] <- cumsum(diffP[j:nDiff])
}
answer <- min(unlist(hold)) #this gives the answer that I ultimately want
```

Hopefully my example above has helped to articulate my question. `answer` contains the correct answer, but I'd rather do this without a `for()` loop in R. Is there a better way to do this calculation, or maybe a name I can put to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem and is a typical interview question!

Most people --me included-- would solve it using a O(n^2) algorithm but there is in fact a much better algorithm with O(n) complexity. Here is an R implementation of Kadane's algorithm from the link above:

```
max_subarray <- function(A) {
   max_ending_here <- 0
   max_so_far <- 0
   for (x in A) {
      max_ending_here <- max(0, max_ending_here + x)
      max_so_far <- max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
   }
   max_so_far
}
```

Since in your case, you are looking for the *minimum* sub-array sum, you would have to call it like this:

```
-max_subarray(-diffP)
[1] -2
```

(Or you can also rewrite the function above and replace `max` with `min` everywhere.)

Note that, yes, the implementation still uses a `for` loop, but the complexity of the algorithm being O(n) (meaning the number of operations is of the same order as `length(diff)`), it should be rather quick. Also, it won't consume any memory since it only stores and updates a couple variables.

Comment: Hmmmm... "typical interview question" at which oversized software company?